# Extract servers' blocks and values from Nginx conf

Tags: text-processing, awk, nginx

How can we extract nginx server blocks using AWK?
Input

```
server { # php/fastcgi
listen       80;
server_name  domain1.com www.domain1.com;
access_log   logs/domain1.access.log  main;
root         html;

location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1025;
}
}
server { # simple reverse-proxy
listen       80;
server_name  domain2.com www.domain2.com;
access_log   logs/domain2.access.log  main;

# serve static files
location ~ ^/(images|javascript|js|css|flash|media|static)/  {
  root    /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs;
  expires 30d;
}

# pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
location / {
  proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
}
```

How can we match the wanted values and print in one line for each server{} block?

for example

I need to get the values for listen|root|server_name. the desired output is

```
80 domain1.com www.domain1.com html
80 domain2.com www.domain2.com /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs
```

Comment: Is that really how your file is? Do you actually have the second `server` block starting in the middle of a line and not on its own line?

Comment: Oh sorry, It happened while copying. It is actually in the new line.

Comment: Ah. Please be careful with this sort of thing. If they're on separate lines, the problem is much easier and I wouldn't have had to spend so long finding a workaround. Please [edit] and fix the data so that they are correct. My answer will work regardless, but it would have been simpler if they were on separate lines.

Answer (score 5):

Since you can have more than one space-separated value per line, using `awk` is a bit tricky. It is absolutely possible in awk, but it's simpler to use something like Perl instead:

```
$ perl -lne '
    if(/(^| )server / || eof){ 
        print join " ",@ll if $ll[0]; 
        @ll=(); 
    }
    /^(listen|root|server_name)\s+(\S[^;]+)/ && push @ll,$2' file 
80 domain1.com www.domain1.com html
80 domain2.com www.domain2.com /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs
```

The `-lne` means "read the input file line by line (`-n`), strip trailing newlines and add a newline to each `print` call (`-l`) and run the script given by `-e` on each line".

The code:

- `if(/(^| )server / || eof){` : this section will run if the current line contains the word `server` surrounded by spaces or at the start of the line.
- `print join " ",@ll if $ll[0];` : if there is currently anything stored in the array `@ll` (so if the first element of the array, `$ll[0]`, is defined), print the contents of the array joined with a space.
- `@ll=();` : empty the array so we can get the next server's info.
- `/^(listen|root|server_name)\s+(\S[^;]+)/ && push @ll,$2'`: if this line starts with one of the keywords and then has one or more whitespace characters, find the first non-whitespace character and as many non-`;` characters as possible until the end of the line and add this (the parentheses will capture the pattern so "this" is now `$2`) to the array `@ll` for printing.

---

And here's an (ugly) way of doing it in awk:

```
$ awk '
    (/ server\s*\{/){ 
        if(out){
            print out
        }
        out=""
    } 
    ($1=="listen" || $1=="root" || $1=="server_name"){
        gsub(";",""); 
        $1=""; 
        gsub(/^ */,""); 
        out ? out=out" "$0 : out=$0
    }
    END{print out}' file 
80 domain1.com www.domain1.com html
80 domain2.com www.domain2.com /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs
```

Comment: It helped me. Can you explain the awk as well?

Comment: @user3779472 just use the perl. It is simpler and explained. I only included the awk to demonstrate that it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you have tag (aka name aka key) to value pairs in your input data I find it best to first create an array of that mapping (`f[]`) below and then you can just print whatever values you want in whatever order you want under whatever conditions you want just by accessing the array values by their tags.

For example, using any POSIX awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
(NR > 1) && ($1 == "server") { prt() }
{
    tag = $1
    sub(/[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
    sub(/;$/,"")
    f[tag] = $0
}
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    print f["listen"], f["server_name"], f["root"]
    delete f
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
80 domain1.com www.domain1.com html
80 domain2.com www.domain2.com /var/www/virtual/big.server.com/htdocs
```

If you're stuck with a non-POSIX awk that doesn't support character classes then just replace `[:space:]` with  `\t` (that's a blank char then backslash then `t`).

There are briefer ways to just get the output in your specific question but the above approach gives you the flexibility to trivially print, test, reorder, modify, etc. these and any other fields you want to do anything with.